# Publish blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have developed an app in BB (5 - 7 OS) with push service. i have been testing it with push service in development mode and now I want to upload it to RIM to publish.

I have ordered push keys for production and I am waiting for them. After that, what do I need to do?

I think, I have to recompile  my app with the new key and create the bundle for uploading. Where do I have to upload it? Do I need to do something else efore creating the bundle?

Comment: After getting the credentials for production, change old values of id and ur with the new values. then build your app and sign it. Then upload your app into blackberry appworld.

Comment: I think this link will be help full for you to upload Blackberry Application on Blackberry Appworld http://infotech4share.blogspot.in/2013/11/steps-to-upload-application-on.html